# "message": "Invalid redirect_uri:"

Tags: facebook, redirect

So a few months ago my facebook app worked, and now I get a:

```
{ "error": { "type": "OAuthException", "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration." }
```

So I googled about that, and read that the cause might be that I didn't specify a site domain in the app settings. So I did that, but Facebook told me that this won't work unless I also specified a website or mobile device adress. But up to now I had this just set as App and neither Website nor mobile thingy. So now I also have to check "website" in addition to "application?" This is confusing.
Anyway, so I thought "whatever" and set it also as website in the app settings. But I still get the same error.

I read something about a channel file? So I have to create one of those or something?

I'm lost and thankful for any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 0):

This error is almost always when you're trying to redirect the user to a URL other than your app or website, check that you're actually redirecting them to the correct place

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Well when the user is not logged in when trying to access the app using the `http://apps.facebook.com/someapp` url, then the user should get redirected using  `top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + APP_ID + '&scope=' + PERMS + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URI + params;` The REDIRECT_URI variable is exactly the canvas url (again "`http://apps.facebook.com/someapp"`). I don't see the error.